# How much to charge for a blog post in the UK?

Tags: blog, freelance, jobs

I have a client who is based in London who wants between 500-1000 word blog post written each week. How, much should I charge? The blog post will have a few images in it. The quality should be high and require some research as it is a specialist subject (not academic).

Comment: Pro Science Fiction/Fantasy short stories (I know - those aren't technical blog posts, but still...) in the US generally go for around $.05 or $.06 a word, which would give you a whopping $60 per week at the best - That's about 45 pounds or so.  Not terribly exciting unless you're also going for the "exposure" factor.  The result is that you get paid a little while the blog gets paid a lot (maybe) through advertising by using your expertise.  I'm not familiar with how the getting paid to blog model works though, so I think it'll be interesting to see what the answers are.

Comment: How long do you estimate it will take you to write each post?

Answer (score 4):

There is no "usual" rate because writing skills are a very wide spectrum ranging from "kid out of high school who thinks they are a writer because their Dragonball fanfic got over 2000 views" and "world renowned bestseller author whose name alone guarantees millions of readers".

1. Think about how much you consider your writing services worth per hour. While estimating that number, keep in mind that as a self-employed author you have risks and costs an employee has not. For example, finding clients and negotiating with them is work you don't get paid for. To compensate for that you need to charge them more.
2. Think about how much time you would need to write a blog post in the quality the client expects.
3. Multiply the two numbers.
4. Add a bit on top to leave room for negotiation (Ferengi Rules of Acquisiton #212: *If they accept your first offer, you either asked too little or offered too much*)